# How can I get data from a JSON file in .net, that comes thorugh an HTTP PUT request from Angular?

Tags: c#, json, angular, http, backend

I have a project, and I have to rewrite the Frontend from CSHTML to Angular. I set up the register page in Angular, and using a PUT request I can send the data to the backend. But I can't seem to extract the different variables from it. My main problem is that I don't know how to acces the file that comes in when I send the PUT request. The request:

```
register() {
    var body = {
      ID: '',
      firstName: this.registerModel.value.firstName,
      lastName: this.registerModel.value.lastName,
      gender: this.registerModel.value.gender,
      email: this.registerModel.value.email,
      password: this.registerModel.value.password
    };
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/Register/Register', body)
  }
```

I call the function when the user submits the form:

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log("clicked");
    this.service.register().subscribe()
  }
```

And the function that it calls looks through the Json where the existing users are stored, and should compare them (return Json values are only for testing):

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Register(User user)
        {
            
            string path = @"./Data/Users.json";
            //Instantiate User
            User newUser = new User();
            Guid ID = Guid.NewGuid();

            newUser.ID = ID;
            newUser.firstName = user.firstName;
            newUser.lastName = user.lastName;
            newUser.email = user.email;
            newUser.gender = user.gender;
            newUser.password = user.password;

            if (user.firstName == null || user.lastName == null
                || user.email == null || user.gender == null || user.password == null)
            {
                ViewData["message"] = "Please Fill all fields!";
                var data = "null in variables";
                return Json(new { data = data });
            }

            string fileContent;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
                users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(fileContent);

                foreach (User current in users)
                {
                    if (current.email == newUser.email)
                    {
                        ViewData["message"] = "Already exists!";
                        var data3 = "existing user";
                        return Json(new { data3 = data3 });
                    }
                }

                users.Add(newUser);

                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
            }

            var data2 = "succes";
            return Json(new { data2 = data2 });
        }
```

Comment: Show the code that calls the register function?

Comment: @MikeOne Sorry, I forgot to include that. Added.

Comment: What is user when you debug this call?  Null?

Comment: @Mason11987 Yes, the response is NULL, the first check fails.

Comment: .subscribe ( response => console.log(response)?

Comment: What Type is `User` resolving to? Is it the type you expect or is it `HttpContext.Current.User`?

Comment: @MikeOne Logging the response gives the same output: the variables are NULL

Comment: @Crowcoder How can I check that?

Comment: If you are in Visual Studio you can just hover your mouse over it and there will be a tool tip. You can also set your cursor in it and Go To Definition (F12)

Comment: @Crowcoder I could not for the life of me find the type. But this is the definiton:
`public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: You can't click on "User" and press F12?

Comment: @Crowcoder Doing so just takes me to the definition I linked above

Comment: OK, then that answers the question and it is not the issue that I thought it might be. I thought you might be using the wrong User class. You sometimes have to be careful when you name a Type the same thing as another Type that is used by your project already.

Comment: @BakosDominik Have you logged `body` right before you send the http request, and checked that you are actually sending values? You haven't shown what `this.registerModel` is or how you populate it.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton, yeah my money is on body not being populated when it's sent.

BakosDominik, you can also use the network tab of your browser under develoepr tools to determine exactly what you're sending to you're api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve the problem. I hat to add a few modifications to the controller, and the Startup.cs file. I will post code snippets when I can access the PC the code is on. But shortly: I had to add APIController and routing to the controller, the function needed a fromBody tag, and I had to change a line in the Startup.Cs file. Now it runs perfectly.